# Windows System programming

Tags: c, windows, winapi

Hi i am new to windows system programming and interested in working in it completely using C and win32 api. Can you please give me suggestions on how I can start and any good books to read. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

Programming Windows, 5th edition ,Charles Petzold will be helpful

Comment: i was going to say that but i think he is more gui oriented than system oriented

Comment: It's **the** book for hardcore win32 coding. None of that MFC or WPM nonsense.

Comment: actually i am more system oriented. but in the process i want to implement even the GUI required for my applications using win32 api

Answer (score 4):

Windows System Programming Fourth Edition
by Johnson M. Hart

http://tinyurl.com/5sgf6ju

This is entirely focused on System Programming, whereas Charles Petzolds' Programming Windows is focused on the GUI elements. Buy both if you can as Petzold's book has some very clear and in depth explanations of important issues skimmed over in Hart. Unicode for instance.

Answer (score 2):

Many people interested in programming using C and win32 api use [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) and are on the MinGW [mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/mingw-users). I've heard (though I can't back it up), that's it's practically the only place to get expert answers on programming win32 with C.